# How to Direct3D Alpha Blending

Tags: c#, direct3d, alphablending, blending

I am trying to display seleveral 3D objects inside a blend parallelepiped container.
Obtained result is unsatisfactory.

First figure seems to be correct
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/QabTkrf2zyIMP0UEuZvmTdMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

And the second is wrong
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/JqnZqeTuomNLqDR5vhizadMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

I use managed directx with c#

Initialization:

```
DxDeviceArea.Transform.Projection = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH((float)Math.PI / 4, 1.0f, 1.0f, MaxSizeArea * 2);
DxDeviceArea.Transform.View = Matrix.LookAtLH(new Vector3(0, 0, MaxSizeArea / 2f), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
DxDeviceArea.RenderState.Lighting = true;
DxDeviceArea.RenderState.CullMode = Cull.CounterClockwise;
DxDeviceArea.RenderState.SourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha;
DxDeviceArea.RenderState.DestinationBlend = Blend.InvSourceAlpha;
DxDeviceArea.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable = true;
DxDeviceArea.RenderState.BlendOperation = BlendOperation.Add;
DxDeviceArea.RenderState.AlphaTestEnable = true;
//Set light
DxDeviceArea.Lights[0].Type = LightType.Directional;
DxDeviceArea.Lights[0].Diffuse = Color.White;
DxDeviceArea.Lights[0].Direction = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
DxDeviceArea.Lights[0].Enabled = true;
```

In render function first step is drawing inside objects
And the second is drawing blend border.

Before drawing second i switch cullmode from CounterClockwise to None

```
DxDeviceArea.RenderState.CullMode = Cull.None;
```

Rotation

```
//rotation
DxDeviceArea.Transform.World *= Matrix.RotationY((-PosX / 300F)) * Matrix.RotationX(PosY / 300F);
```

How can i beat showed issue?

Comment: Are the objects that the translucent box contains translucent as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to draw transparent surfaces correctly, you have to sort them by depth and render them from back to front. You also have to disable z-buffer testing while rendering transparent objects.

Comment: Oh rendering of blend objects is significant harder than I thought... So I used your advise and disable Z buffer before container render. I got container with only frontier polygons rendered and this is enouth for me. Here is image: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/kwH_AZTQfrTjlKAYkviTj9MTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink